# Iterate through a Matrix and continuously sum it without for loop

Tags: python, loops, numpy, matrix, sum

I have 400 2x2 numpy matrices, and I need to sum them all together. I was wondering if there's any better way to do it than using a for loop, as it consumes a lot of time and memory to iterate through a for loop, particularly if I have more matrices (which might be the case in the future) ?

Comment: Can you please provide sample code? How are your 400 matrices stored?

Comment: Do you have a 3d numpy array?

Comment: @CorentinPane They're all on a list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured it out. All my matrices were on a list, so I used

```
np.sum(<list>, axis=0)
```

And it gives me the resultant 2x2 matrix of the sum of all the 400 matrices!